# Having some trouble with a custom validator using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex, customvalidator

I'm having an issue getting a custom validator to work with jQuery.

Here is the function I created to check and see if the textbox contains PO BOX.

```
function valPoBox(sender, args) {
    var hasPObox = "^P\.?\s?O\.?\sB[Oo][Xx].";
    var StreetAddress = $('.streetaddress').val();
    var match = StreetAddress.match(RegExp(hasPObox));
    if (!match) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        sender.ErrorMessage = "Address must not contain P.O. Box";
        $('.valPoBox').attr("ErrorMessage", sender.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

The function fires when I tab out of the textbox and will follow the logic into args.IsValid = false; but it will not display the error message.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The last line that you have `$('.valPoBox').attr("ErrorMessage", sender.ErrorMessage);` isn't actually valid code. The `attr` function sets a HTML attribute on an element. What I'm guessing you want to do is to add a piece of text after the input and show it to the user once it has failed validation.

For example, you could have something like this:

```
<input class="streetaddress" /><span id="PoBoxError"></span>
```

Your JS then turns into something like:

```
    ...
    $('#PoBoxError').html(sender.ErrorMessage);
} else {
    args.IsValid = true;
    $('#PoBoxError').html('');
}
```

This sets the span after the input with your error message, and hides it again once it has passed validation. This is just one of the ways you could accomplish this, other ways involve showing and hiding the content, but I tried to make the answer as close as your original code as possible.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I'm using a CustomValidator in ASP and attempting to set the errormessage through the jquery above. The custom validator has a class of "valPoBox".

Comment: Custom Validators are only fired server side, so you won't be able to set the ErrorMessage attribute on the client by using jQuery or any JavaScript. What would be best is to put it in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` with an `AutoPostback="true"` attribute and convert your JavaScript code into .NET for the `OnChange` event of the input box. Also this question should have the ASP.NET tag as this concerns ASP.NET more than jQuery. :)